# How can I generate RSA private keys encrypted with AES128 or AES256 using openssl?

Tags: openssl

I am writing a server in an embedded system that uses axTLS to provide encryption services.  axTLS cannot handle private keys encrypted using the -des option of the genrsa openssl command but it can handle private keys encrypted with AES128 or AES256.  I have scanned through the documentation for openssl and have been unable to find any options for the genrsa command that will encrypt the private key with anything other than DES, DES3, or IDEA ciphers.  Is there a way to do make the genrsa command use AES ciphers instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-aes128`, `-aes192` and `-aes256` options to `openssl genrsa` encrypt the private key file using AES.